# Nextjs/Vercel error: only absolute URLs are supported. Where is the '.json' in my route params coming from?

Tags: json, url, next.js, vercel

**The Problem:**
I'm new to Next.js (1 month) and Vercel (1 day), and between them something appears to be inserting `.json` in my urls on the `search` route, causing them to fail with error:

```
[GET] /_next/data/9MJcw6afNEM1L-eax6OWi/search/hand.json?term=hand
10:21:52:87
Function Status:None
Edge Status:500
Duration:292.66 ms
Init Duration: 448.12 ms
Memory Used:88 MB
ID:fra1:fra1::ldzhz-1644484912454-0a30b71b6c90
User Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0

TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported    
at getNodeRequestOptions (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/node-fetch/index.js:1:61917)    
at /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/node-fetch/index.js:1:63448    
at new Promise (<anonymous>)    
at Function.fetch [as default] (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/node-fetch/index.js:1:63382)    
at fetchWithAgent (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/node-polyfill-fetch.js:38:39)    
at getServerSideProps (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/730.js:238:28)    
at Object.renderToHTML (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:566:26)    
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)    
at async doRender (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:855:38)    
at async /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-
server.js:950:28

2022-02-10T09:21:53.788Z    994c9544-0bbe-4a68-af83-f0e4c322151e    ERROR   
Error: Your `getServerSideProps` function did not return an object. Did you forget to add a `return`?
at Object.renderToHTML (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:592:19)    
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)    
at async doRender (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:855:38)    
at async /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:950:28    
at async /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/response-cache.js:63:36 {  page: '/search/[term]'}

RequestId: 994c9544-0bbe-4a68-af83-f0e4c322151e Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
```

Though the browser says `https://.../search/hand` as it should.
No such thing is happening on my local server build though, and it works perfectly well.

**Background/Code Snippets:**
The search route is the only route that uses SSR, and is also the only route with this issue. It is a dynamic route, so it seems either next in production or vercel expects some kind of json for it -presumably pre-rendered content-, and is replacing the route URL with json.

Also I have had to use the VERCEL_URL environment variable to prepare a URL for fetch requests, so this may also be messing up the URL, but the .json in the error message makes me think otherwise, since search should not be pre-rendered.

*The Page Structure For the Search Route (Index imports the component in [term] and defines its own getServerSide props to accommodate a search route without a param)*:

```
|-Search
  |- [term].js
  |- Index.js
```

*The Code For `[term].js`*:

```
...
export default function Search({results, currentSearch}){
...
}

export async function getServerSideProps(req) {
  const { criteria, page } = req.query;
  const { term } = req.params || { term: '' };
  try {
    const data = await fetch(`${process.env.VERCEL_URL}/api/search/${term}?criteria=${criteria || 'name'}&page=${page}`);
    const searchRes = await data.json();
    return {
      props: {
        results: searchRes.data,
        currentSearch: searchRes.query
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

*`Index.js` is similar*:

```
import Search from "./[term]";
export default Search;

export async function getServerSideProps(req) {
  const { criteria, page } = req.query;
  const { term } = req.params || { term: '' };
  if(!term){
    return {
      props: {
        results: [],
        currentSearch: {}
      }
    }
  }
  try {
    const data = await fetch(`${process.env.VERCEL_URL}/api/search/${term}?criteria=${criteria || 'name'}&page=${page}`);
    const searchRes = await data.json();
    return {
      props: {
        results: searchRes.data,
        currentSearch: searchRes.query
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

The API I'm trying to fetch from is confirmed to be working, so this problem is strictly regarding pages, or .json being provided to the fetch method from router params.

Comment: Is the endpoint you're trying to fetch from inside `getServerSideProps` a Next.js internal API route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would turn out that `VERCEL_URL` **is actually an absolute URL** (It does not include a protocol). I had to deploy console.log statements to find this. A little embarrassed that I missed it in the [docs](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables).

- The `.json` was not actually in the `query` or `params`, and therefore not in the fetch request. The fetch failed because the url had no protocol.
- The .json in the page url must be from Next's internal operations, and does not mean the page is being built ahead of time. Yes it is being rendered using some json, *but my thinking that the json indicates a pre-rendered page(SSG/ISR) was wrong*. This must mean Server Side Rendering will also make use of such json, but only at runtime, when the request is made.
- The use of `.json` after the params slug in the GET requests for a page has no bearing on the internal flow of your app, provided it has worked correctly. If you see it in error messages, know that it is from Next and examine other parts of the code at the point of failure.
- The page structure I attempted (`[param].js` + `index.js` in the same
  directory) is fine, which is why my local build could work properly.

I want to delete this question because the solution is essentially one that a thorough look in the docs would have revealed, but at the same time I think the mistake itself is an easily made one and that some of the conclusions listed above(particularly the one about json being used in all next routes) could save time spent debugging for some new users of Next/Vercel.

Comment: To clarify, the JSON file is the result of running `getServerSideProps` when the page is requested on client-side navigations. So your assumption about it being used for SSR is correct, and it's also not related to the issue you were experiencing. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#when-does-getserversideprops-run for more details.

Comment: @juliomalves yes, I know now that it isn't related, but I thought it was (originally I thought the json shouldn't show for SSR), and that's how I muddied the question.